# Making a clicked row editable

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm creating the following table dynamically with an edit button on each line.

```
<tr>
<td><?php echo $f1; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $f2; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $f3; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $f4; ?></td>
<td><input class="edbuttons" type="button" value="Edit"></td>
</tr>
```

When the edit button is clicked I'd like the cells in the row to be converted to text boxes, but I can't work out how to do it. I've spent hours searching the net for the right syntax, but can't find anything that does what I need.

The idea is that when edit is clicked the user can modify the data on the row and click a save or cancel button that would appear in place of the edit button.

I've added a class to the edit button to use as a selector, but I'm not sure if that's the most efficient method.

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: It is doable but why reinvent the wheeel. Check this plugin which already addresses the same thing: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Comment: 2 reasons to "reinvent the wheel" - 1) good learning experience for javascript, and 2) takes very little code to implement this.  Just my opinion obviously.

Comment: I was hoping to use this as a learning experience, hence the DIY approach, but it was taking too long. Thanks for the jeditable suggestion. I've reworked the table using this module and it now works really well!

Answer (score 0):

Jeditable is a good plugin for that.

You may also want to look at the new html5 `contenteditable` attribute. Setting it to true will allow you to edit the text inside.

http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I decided to go with jeditable.

Answer (score 0):

Put both the text and an input box with that text inside the table cell:

```
<td id="myText">
    <div>My text goes here</div>
    <input type="text" name="whatever" value="My text goes here" style="display:none;"/>
</td>
```

Then have your edit button toggle both of them:

```
//if you have jquery:
$('#myText div').toggle();
$('#myText input').toggle();
```

If you aren't using jquery, you can use javascript to change the display of each.

Obviously there are other little things to work out, but that's the general idea for a way to make it appear like you're making text turn into an input box.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like an elegant solution. In the end I went with jeditable, as it seems to do exactly what I want as is dead easy to implement! :-)